# Disadvantage of multilayer perceptron over CNN

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, conv-neural-network

Suppose I train a binary classifier - a dog or not a dog, images are input, so the question is, let's say I use a multilayer perceptron as a classifier and suppose I train it using images of dogs whose face is in the center of the image, and then if I submit a photo of dog, on which her face is located in the corner, then the perceptron will not be able to correctly classify

But if I use CNN, then it will be able to recognize the dog in this case. Am I right?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is not so simple. In short the answer is **no**, there is no **guarantee** this will happen. While MLP has a high-ish chance of failing, it does not have to, it depends what it ended up learning as discriminating factor. And symmetrically CNNs **are not** translation invariant (unless by CNN you mean lack of a single linear layer). They can fail if you move an object around, they are just **less** affected than MLPs.